# ¿Como generar un .jpeg desde un archivo .csv?

Tags: python

tengo inquietudes de como generar un archivo .jpeg desde un .csv
Mi código está generando el archivo pero mal, solo una línea de cuadrados negros y blancos. La imagen ya tiene un proceso de desocompresión. De antemano, muchas gracias.

```
newImage = decompression(image)

with open("descomprimido.csv", mode='w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for line in newImage:
        writer.writerow(line)


print(np.array(newImage) == im)
outputImage = Image.fromarray(np.array(newImage), "L")
outputImage.save("ArchivoDes.jpeg")
```

Comment: Puedes compartir un ejemplo de las líneas existentes en el csv?